# Update migrations to import new content

Tags: 8, migrations, updating

I'm using migrate upgrade drush command to generate migrations from a live DB of website.
So content is created during my migrations. How can I do an update of these migrations to import new content when re-run migrations ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use property [high_water_property](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/migrate/tests/modules/migrate_high_water_test/migrations/high_water_test.yml#n5).

Comment: thanks, do exist an explanation to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `track_changes` option, ex.

```
source:
   plugin: d7_node
   node_type: article
   # Allows to import changed as well as new records from the source.
   track_changes: true
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-source-plugins/overview-of-migrate-source-plugins#track_changes

Comment: do I need to add it in my custom migration yml files ? What about default migrations created by migrate module ?